# google chrome not show images

Tags: facebook, image, google-chrome

google chrome and also facebook never display images. some photos display some are hidden , any one can help me solve this problem. my friend PC also has same problem. as shown in the photo below:
[image shows where facebook never shows images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZIn8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If Google Chrome doesnt show any images on any website like Facebook, you should try to start the Browser in private browsing mode.

The Google Chrome Help Site gives some more pretty neat tips how you could try to solve this problem ( Clearing your Browser cache & cookies, turn off extensions and turn on javascript ).

They also give some good instructions how to do these thing.

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/112568?hl=en